# What is a power cube?

Tags: ingress

I see in my item repository that there is a filter for "power cubes" along with the regular assortment of weapons, resonators, keys, and media. Even after quite a bit of playing, I don't have any.

What is a power cube and what role do they play in the game?

Comment: The Power Cube filter for items was only recently added to Ingress and they are not dropping yet as confirmed by a Niantic Labs employee on Google+ - https://plus.google.com/u/0/107179591490960059904/posts/ffhicQp1RSS

Comment: Note that at least some media objects look like little cubes on the map, and spin when you click on them.  But they aren't power cubes.  Confusing....

Answer (score 10):

Someone posted this "Power cube" summary on the Ingress community. She tested it out so others would not make the same mistakes as she did to waste these "precious/mysterious" cubes.

> What does it do?
>  It's essentially like a mana/health potion from
>   any other game. It recharges your XM bar up to the value of the cube
>   itself. So a level 4 cube will inject you with 4k XM.
>
> Does it increase your XM bar above cap?
>  No. It only refills the
>   bar you already have (up to its own value).
>
> What happens if it's worth more than the XM you need?
>  In short,
>   the overspill fizzles. The cube is consumed utterly on use, and will
>   only give you up to the full amount, as much as you have room for. For
>   example, I had 1348 XM short of 100%, used a 4000XM cube, so I gained
>   1348 to bring me to 100% and the other 2652XM just dissipated into the
>   ether.
>
> What does it look/sound like?
>  It's pretty nifty! Swirley gold XM
>   droplets spiral around you while a "chargin' mah laz0rs!" sound effect
>   revs up. There is no residue once the cube's power has been used.
>   EDIT: Courtesy of +Fevenis Silverwind : Power Cube animation (RAW)
>
> Can you use cubes of a higher level than yourself?
>  Nope! The 'Use'
>   button is greyed out, and trying to click it gets an "insufficient
>   access" error.
>
> Can you use a cube while already at 100% XM?
>  Yes, and it'll be
>   totally wasted. So don't. (Thanks +Alexandre Luna Barros for the
>   sacrifice).
>
> I'm not getting any cubes from hacking, whassup with that?!?
>  They
>   are dropping for people, but it still seems to be rather hit and miss.
>   My theory is that the portals need their 'loot tables' to be refreshed
>   post-update, either by flipping them, or waiting on the daily decay.
>   Hopefully over the course of the next day any stubborn portals will
>   get updated, and in the meantime try not to get too frustrated. Also,
>   bad luck is bad, but not permanent, so try not to despair if you're
>   burning out and still not seeing any just yet!

Link to G+: https://plus.google.com/113226483052150160303/posts/2dSSuN43Xt2

Answer (score 8):

From [here](http://decodeingress.me/2013/04/04/power-cubes-are-here/):

They contain their Level * 1000 XM.

Warning: They will not function until the next Ingress app update!

Answer (score 1):

just got one, options are to drop or use and it has 5000 XM....assume it recharges XM

Comment: Interesting. Can you report back and [edit] your answer with details when you have more than an assumption to go on for what it does and how you use it?