# How do I use Power Cubes?

Tags: ingress

[I know what it is](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112346/what-is-a-power-cube), but, how do I use it? I have three buttons when I navigate to a Power Cube in the Inventory, Use, Drop and Recycle. What is the purpose of each of those?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- **Use**: consumes the Power Cube, making you recover an amount of XM equal to 1000 * Power Cube Level;
- **Drop**: drops the Cube in the position where you're standing. Can be recovered by any agent, regardless of their faction. Dropped objects disappear after 24 hours;
- **Recycle**: consumes the Power Cube, making you recover an amount of XM equal to 10 * Power Cube Level.

Recycling a Power Cube is a waste, since you get 100 times the amount of XM by using it.

Please notice that the Drop and Recycle buttons aren't exclusive to Power Cubes, the same functionalities apply to any other item in your inventory.